# Euclid's Lemma in a PID: irreducibles are prime: $ \pi\mid ab\Rightarrow \pi\mid a\,$ or $\pi\mid b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, proof-explanation, principal-ideal-domains

I am studying ring theory and I am having a hard time understanding a part of a proof of a certain theorem. Note that in my lecture notes, a ring is by definition commutative with $1$. Let $R$ be a ring, then the set of units of $R$ is denoted by $R^*$.

Consider the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain (PID) and $\pi\in R$ irreducible. For any $a,b\in R$ with $\pi|ab$ we have $\pi|a$ or $\pi|b$.

The following is the first part of the proof from my lecture notes:

> Consider the ideal $(a,\pi)$. Since $R$ is a PID this ideal is generated by a single element, which we call g. Note that $g|\pi$. Hence either $g$ is a unit, or $g=\epsilon\pi$ with $\epsilon\in R^*$. In the second case, since $g|a$ we also get $\pi|a$ and our assertion is proven.

The second part of the proof covers the case in which $g$ is a unit; I understand what's going on there (under the assumption that $g$ is indeed a unit) so I've omitted it. Please note that this is the proof word by word, i.e. I have quoted it from my lecture notes.

First of all, is it true that, since $(g)=(a,\pi)$ we have $\{rg\ |\ r\in R\}=\{r_1a+r_2\pi\ |\ r_1,r_2\in R\}$ and by choosing $r_1=0$ and $r_2=1$ we have $rg=\pi$ for some $r\in R$, thus $g|\pi$? If this is true, then by similar reasoning one can proof that $g|a$ (which is stated in the last sentence of the proof).

Next, the proof says that $g$ is either a unit or $g=\epsilon\pi$ for some unit $\epsilon$. By definition, we see from the factorisation above that either $g$ or $r$ is a unit. The first case corresponds to the statement in the proof that $g$ can be a unit. But if $g$ is not a unit, why is $g=\pi\epsilon$ for some unit $\epsilon$?

Lastly, how does $\pi|a$ follow from all that has been said in the proof?

**EDIT**:

As requested by a user in the comments, here is the second part of the proof in my lecture notes, along with the first one for easy reading:

> Consider the ideal $(a,\pi)$. Since $R$ is a PID this ideal is generated by a single element, which we call g. Note that $g|\pi$. Hence either $g$ is a unit, or $g=\epsilon\pi$ with $\epsilon\in R^*$. In the second case, since $g|a$ we also get $\pi|a$ and our assertion is proven.
>
> Now suppose  that $g$ is a unit and hence $(a,\pi)=R$. In this case there exist $x,y\in R$ such that $ax+\pi y=1$. Multiply by $b$ to get $abx+\pi by=b$. Both terms on the left are divisible by $\pi$. Hence the sum $b$ is also divisible by $\pi$ which proves our theorem.

Comment: The ideal $I=(a,\pi)= \{r_1a+r_2\pi\ |\ r_1,r_2\in R\}$, but since $R$ is a PID you know that there is a single generator $g$ such that $I=\{rg\ |\ r\in R\}$.  As $\pi \in I$ you know $g|\pi$, but $\pi$ is irreducible.  Either $g$ is a unit or it's an associate of $\pi$, i.e. $g=\pi\epsilon$ for some unit $\epsilon$  If $g|a$ then $g=\pi\epsilon|a$, but since $\epsilon$ is a unit $\pi|a$

Comment: What do you mean by associate of $\pi$?

Comment: $\pi$ times a unit, so $\pi \epsilon$.  Point is that's the definition of an irreducible.

Comment: Could you please include the 2nd part of the proof too. I'd like to explain a more conceptual way to view the *entire* proof

Comment: @BillDubuque Sure thing! I have added the second part.

Comment: @Tyron Thanks, I added an explanation. It might take a bit more effort to understand, but the rewards will be well worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $gr=\pi$, and $g$ is not a unit, then $r$ is (by definition of $\pi$ being irreducible), hence we can write $g=r^{-1}\pi$, so your $\varepsilon$ is nothing else than $r^{-1}$.

Also since $g$ divides $a$, any associated element (multiple of $g$ by a unit) does  too, in particular $\pi$. Indeed, since $a=a_1g$, we deduce $a=a_1r(r^{-1}g)=a_1r\pi$.

Comment: I assume that the first "I" should be "If" and "Un deed" should be "Indeed"?

Comment: Perfect guess. Sorry for the typos, and thanks for pointing them! I suppose the second typo was because I was thinking two things at a time (and didn't check what was actually typed :o))

Comment: No problem! Also, perhaps it's better to use a different symbol in $a=bg$ for the sake of consistency. Even though it is pretty clear what you mean, it could be confused with the $b$ in the initial theorem in my question.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't even think of checking the notations. Fixed

Comment: Thank you! You overlooked the final $b$ though. Sorry for being such a nitpick about this.

Comment: No problem. Notation have to be consistent, especially for other people to whom this answer might be useful.

Answer (score 6):

The proof is an exact PID translation of a well-known proof that an irreducible integer $p$ is prime (by a version of of Euclid's Lemma). Highlighting this analogy greatly clarifies the conceptual essence of the matter (and answers your question and then some).

**Theorem** $ $ irreducible $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\ $ or $\ p\mid b\ $ in $\Bbb Z,\,$ since, with $\,(x,y) := \gcd(x,y)$

$(a,p) = p\ $ or $\,1,\ $  by $\,(a,p)\mid p\,$ and $\,p\,$ is $\rm\color{#06f}{irreducible}$

$(a,p) = p\ \Rightarrow\ p \mid a.\ $ In the other case, employing $\,\rm\color{#c00}{DL}$ = [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242)

$(a,p) = 1\ \Rightarrow\ p\mid b,\, \ $ by $\,p\mid ab,pb\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid (ab,pb)\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{DL}}= (a,p)b = b.$ $\ \ \small\bf QED$

For principal ideals $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides}$, $ $ i.e.  $\,(a)\supset (b)\!\iff\! a\mid b,\,$ so translating with this:

**Theorem** $ $ irreducible $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\ $ or $\ p\mid b\ $ in a PID, since, with $\,(x,y) := xR\!+\!yR\,$

$(a,p) = (p)\ $ or $\,(1),\ $  by $\,(a,p)\supseteq (p)\,$ and $\,p\ \rm\color{#06f}{irreducible}$ $\Rightarrow(p)\ \rm\color{#06f}{maximal}$ $ $ [proof below]

$(a,p) = (p)\ \Rightarrow\ (p) \supseteq (a)\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid a$

$(a,p) = (1)\ \Rightarrow\ p\mid b,\, \ $ by $\ (p)\supseteq (ab),(pb)\,\Rightarrow\,(p)\supseteq (ab,pb) = (a,p)b = (b).$ $\ \ \small\bf QED$

Note: above we used that, in a PID, since $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides}$, we have

$\qquad\qquad\begin{eqnarray} (p)\,\text{ is $\rm\color{#06f}{maximal}$} 
&\iff&\!\!\ (p)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{\rm\color{#0a0}{container}}\,\ (d)\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ has no proper}\,\ {\rm\color{#c00}{divisor}}\,\ d\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ is $\rm\color{#06f}{irreducible}$}\\
\end{eqnarray}$

**Remark** $ $ Further, notice that $\,(a,b) = (d)\iff d\,$ is a gcd of $a,b,\,$ since

$$ c\mid a,b\iff (c)\supseteq (a),(b)\iff (c)\supseteq (a,b)\!=\!(d)\iff c\mid d\quad$$

therefore $\,d\,$ is a gcd of $\,a,b\,$ since it satisfies the [universal definition of a GCD](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242).

Hence in a PID, $\,(a,b)\,$ can be read as both an ideal and a gcd, facilitating said analogy.

In fact, the above proof generalizes to show that any *maximal* ideal is prime  - see [Euclid's Lemma in Bezout form, gcd form and ideal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242), which highlights the role the various distributive laws play in the Bezout, gcd, and ideal forms of the proof.

More generally, any ideal maximal in the complement of a monoid is prime - [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146757/242).

When first learning about PIDs, it will be very instructive to view them as generalization of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ and, as above, translate well-know proofs from $\,\Bbb Z\,$ to PID language.

Comment: Great answer as usual.

Comment: Where can I find the proof for: $\,(a)\supset (b)\!\iff\! a\mid b,\,$ in a PID ?

Comment: I already understand the equivalence, I saw it with a particular example :)

Comment: @Annet. See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1291435/242)