# Ideals in polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

I am facing this problem:

> Prove that there is a bijection between the monic divisors of $x^n−1$ in $F[x]$ and the ideals of $F[x]/\left<x^n−1\right>$.

I tried to find how the ideals in $F[x]/\left<x^n−1\right>$ are represented and find the connection to the monic divisors but I did not find any connection.

I think I am missing something very clear. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use or prove (use Euclidean division for it) that the ideals are principal. Then, use the definition of quotient to get that the preimage in $F[x]$ of any such ideal is an ideal in $F[x]$ that contains $\langle x^n-1\rangle$.

Comment: There's nothing special about $x^n-1$ here.

Comment: Use the [general correspondence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69578/242) between ideals in a ring and its quotient, and [contains = divides for prinicipal ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346348/242).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about $x^n-1$.

The key fact is that the ideals containing $\langle f(x)\rangle$ are exactly those generated by the divisors of $f(x)$ and monic divisors are canonical representatives of these ideals.

This follows from the ring isomorphisms theorems for $F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ and the fact that $F[x]$ is a PID.