# Ring theory - irreducibility and primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $D$ be an integral domain and let $a\in D$. Suppose that every pair of elements $a,b\in D$ (not both zero) have a $\gcd c$ such that $c=as+bt$ for some $s,t\in D$. Prove that if $d\in D$ is irreducible then it is prime.

I know that in a PID we have an element is irreducible iff it is prime, but I can't see how to use this in this example. I thought initially we could assume $d$ to be irreducible, with $d=ab$ so that $a$ or $b$ must be $1$ by definition of irreducibility. We require $c=1$ for primality but there doesn't seem to be an easy way of proving this.

Comment: The PID proof only uses the gcd distributive law or Bezout - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346348/242) in the linked dupe. Note that your Bezout hypothesis implies all gcds exist, cf. 2nd dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't understand the relation to the question...

Comment: The [linked theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346348/242) show how to give such proofs, either in gcd language or ideal language.  Is that not what you seek?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1162403/242).