# A necessary and sufficent condition for a ring to be a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I came across the following question in Hungerford's Algebra:

> An integral domain $R$ is a UFD iff every non-zero prime ideal
>   contains a nonzero prime principal ideal.

The forward direction is easy. However, I still don't know how to show the backward direction. I know that I need to show the following statement:

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in Z^+}$ be a sequence in $R$ such that:$$(a_1)\subseteq(a_2)\subseteq(a_3)\subseteq.....$$Then $\exists N\in \mathbb{Z^+}\forall n\geq N[(a_n)=(a_N)]$

But I couldn't figure out how to prove it. Any hints would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I won't be so sure that you need to prove exactly that statement. See [here](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/EquivalentDefinitionsForUFD.html) and also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15354/characterizations-of-ufd-and-euclidean-domain-by-ideal-theoretic-conditions).

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/150848/23500) for this and more.