# In a noetherian integral domain every non invertible element is a product of irreducible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, noetherian

> I want to prove that in a noetherian ring $R$ which is also an integral domain, every non invertible element can be expressed as product of irreducible elements.

I really do not know where to start. Can someone give me hint how to prove this?

Comment: Here is what I would try first: Take a non-unit $x$. If it is irreducible, we are done. Otherwise, write $x = yz$ where $y, z$ are non-units. If both are irreducible, we are done. Otherwise, write each of them that is reducible as a product of two non-units. Rinse, repeat, and then use Noetherianness of the ring to show that we eventually have to come to a stop. That last part might be easy, it might be hard. I don't know.

Comment: Thank you very much, sounds good. I will try to bring that idea on the paper.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $X$ be your set of nonzero, nonunits which cannot be written as a product of irreducibles. Towards a contradiction, suppose $X\neq\emptyset$, and pick $x_0\in X$. Then $x_0$ itself is not irreducible, so we may write $x_0=xy$, where $x$ and $y$ are nonzero nonunits. If both $x$ and $y$ can be written as a product of irreducibles, then $x_0$ can as well, a contradiction. So at least one of $x$ and $y$ is not a product of irreducibles, say $x$. Call it $x_1\in X$. Then $(x_0)\subset (x_1)$.

Continue this process to yield an ascending chain
$$
(x_0)\subset (x_1)\subset\cdots
$$
in $R$. Now use the fact that $R$ is Noetherian to find a contradiction.

> Since $R$ is Noetherian, $(x_n)=(x_{n+1})$ for some $n$. By our construction, $x_n=yx_{n+1}$ for $y$ a nonunit. But then $x_{n+1}\in (x_n)=(yx_{n+1})$, so for some nonzero $z\in R$, we have $x_{n+1}=zyx_{n+1}$. By cancellation, since we are in a domain, $1=yz$, so $y$ is a unit, a contradiction. So $X=\emptyset$.

Comment: You might find of interest the remark in my answer, and the papers it links to.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks!

Comment: @BenWest I guess it is easy but I cannot see why $x$ and $y$ are nonunits

Comment: @GiorgosKosmas It follows by definition of $x_0$ not being irreducible, i.e., $x_0$ is reducible, which means there exists some factorization of $x_0$ into a product of nonunits, these factors are our $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @BenWest Oh of course.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\ $ Suppose not, and consider the set of principal ideals generated by all counterexamples. By ACC it contains a maximal element $(r),\,$ and $r$ is reducible $\,r = st.\,$ But by maximality, $\,s,t\,$ have irreducible factorizations, thus so too does $\,r = st,\,$ contradiction.

**Remark** $\ $ Interpreted positively, the proof shows if $S$ is the set of principal ideals  disjoint from a monoid $M$ then $(r)$ is maximal in $\,S \iff r\,$ is irreducible. This is a generalization of the well-known case where $\,M = \{1\},\,$ i.e. $\ (r)$ is maximal among principal ideals $\iff r$ is rreducible.

This is a specal case of a wide class of results where elements satisfying such maximality properties are irreducible or prime, e.g. see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44488/242) One beautiful example along these lines is a [famous theorem of Kaplansky](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/150848/242) that a domain is a UFD $\iff$ every prime ideal $\ne 0$ contains a prime $\ne 0$ (or, equivalently, every prime ideal is generated by primes).

Comment: May I ask what ACC means?

Comment: Ascending Chain Condition on ideals. Which definition of Noetherian are you using?

Comment: Ok, so this is the condition that for every chain $(c_i)_{i\in I}$ s.t $c_i\subset c_{i+1}$ there exist some $k\in I$ s.t $\forall j>k$ we have that $c_k=c_j$? We had that this is equivalent to every set of ideal contains some maximal ideal with respect to inclusion and it is equal to that every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: @user135025 Right. Also equivalent is: every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: @user135025 I added some further pedagogical remarks that may shed more light on the essence of the matter. You will meet many more analogous results having this form later if you study number theory or commutative algebra.

Comment: @BillDubuque Where did you use the fact that $R$ is integral domain? Is it necessary for $R$ to be integral domain so the result still holds?