# Factorization into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$ with square-free $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I'm trying to arrive at a proof that every nonzero $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$  square-free) that is not an unit can be factored into the product of irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$.$\\$

I also have the following norm defined: $N(a+ib\sqrt{n})=a^2+nb^2$ and the prior knowledge that $N(\alpha)=1 \iff \alpha$ is an unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$

I thought of proving by induction on $N(\alpha)=n \geq2$ as $\alpha$ is not an unit.

If we have $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$ with $N(\alpha)=2$ then:$\alpha=\beta \gamma \implies N(\alpha)=N(\beta)N(\gamma) \implies 2= N(\beta)N(\gamma) \implies N(\beta)=1 \lor N(\gamma)=1 \implies \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]^{\ast}  \lor \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]^{\ast}$

Suppose that $N(\alpha)=n>2$ and that the result is valid for $N(\beta)< n$. If $\alpha$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$, $\alpha=\omega\zeta$ with $\omega;\zeta \notin \mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]^{\ast} \cup \{0\} $. But now as $1<N(\omega);N(\zeta)<n$, we have by I.H. that $\omega$ and $\zeta$ are product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$ and it follows that $\alpha$ is product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{n}]$.

Comment: But these rings are not UFD for $n\ge 3$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-n-ge-3-not-a-ufd).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, is the result above a sufficient condition for $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt(n)]$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ square-free to be an UFD?

Comment: No. In fact, it is enough that $R$ is Noetherian, so that every nonunit can be written as a finite product of irreducible elements. Of course your ring is Noetherian, because it is a quotient of $\Bbb Z[x]$, which is Noetherian. So what you are trying to prove follows from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714719/in-a-noetherian-integral-domain-every-non-invertible-element-is-a-product-of-irr).