# Inverting elements of an integral domain to get a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R = \Bbbk[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(p)$, where $\Bbbk$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and where $p \in \Bbbk[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is prime, so that $R$ is a domain. In general, $R$ is not a UFD: one such example is $\Bbbk[w,x,y,z]/(wx-yz)$, where $wx=yz$ has two factorizations into irreducibles. Obviously, one can invert every element of $R$ to get a field, and hence a UFD, but I'm interested in only inverting a subset of elements of $R$:

> Let $p \in \Bbbk[x_1, \dots, x_n]$  be prime. Is $\Bbbk[x_1^{\pm 1}, \dots, x_n^{\pm 1}]/(p)$ a UFD? If this isn't true in general, can any simple hypotheses be placed on $p$ to guarantee that it is a UFD?

Comment: You may find of interest the Remark on Nagata';s Lemma about localization of UFDs in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/817031/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $k[x_1^{\pm 1}, \dots, x_n^{\pm 1}]/(p)$ is not a UFD in general.
For example if $p(x,y)=(y-1)^2-(x-1)^3\in k[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1}]$, then  the quotient ring $R=k[x^{\pm 1},y^{\pm 1}]/(p)$ is not a UFD, as witnessed by the two factorizations of $(\bar y-1)^2=(\bar x-1)^3\in R$ ( There are details to check, like irreducibility of $\bar y-1$ and $\bar x-1$).

Comment: Let me see if I've understood well this example: one can start with $k[t^2,t^3]$ which is isomorphic to $k[x,y]/((y-1)^2-(x-1)^3)$. But if one inverts $t^2$ and $t^3$ we get $k[t,t^{-1}]$ which is a UFD. Then remark that $k[t^2,t^3]=k[t^2+1,t^3+1]$ and invert  $t^2+1$ and $t^3+1$. This way $t^2$ and $t^3$ remain irreducible and $(t^2)^3=(t^3)^2$ still provides a non-unique decomposition.

Comment: Dear @ user26857: yes, you are of course right (as usual).