# Proving that $[2]$ is a prime element in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ but it's not irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I came up to the example above in the title in order to show an element of a ring can be prime but it may fail to be irreducible.

$\mathbb{Z}_{6} = \lbrace [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] \rbrace$ and I would like to show $[2] \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ is a prime element but it is not an irreducible element. Recall an element $p$ of a ring is **prime** if $p | ab$ for every other elements $a$ and $b$ in the ring, then $p | a$ or $p |b$. Also, an element $a$ of a ring is **irreducible** if whenever $a=bc$ then either $b$ or $c$ is a unit. In order to prove the fact $[2]$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ we should assume there are $[a], [b] \in  \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ such that $[2] \: | \:  [a][b]=[ab]$. And from here I should proof $[2] | [a]$ or $[2] | [b]$. No problem proving a particular case, for instance $[a] = [4]$ and $[b] = [3]$. So, $[4] [3] = [12]= [0]$ and since $[2] [3] = [6] = [0]$ it yields that $[2]$ divides $[4][3]$ and obviously $[2]$ divides $[4]$.  My question is that in order to proof $[2]$ is indeed a prime element of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ it suffices to prove it like I did for all elements $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ such that $[2] \: | \: [a][b] $ or there is a general way to prove $[2]$ is prime?  For the last one I tried the following:

If $[2] \: | \: [a] [b]= [ab]$ for $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}$. Then there is an element $[k] \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ such that $[2][k] = [a][b]$. The last means $6t= 2k-ab$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ but I cannot come from here the existance of an $[s] \in \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ such that $[s][2]= [a]$ or $[s][2] = [b]$ :/

Also, no doubt convincing about $[2]$ is irreducible, because $[2]= [2] [4]$ and neither $[2]$ nor $[4]$
are units in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

Comment: Your last sentence shows [2] is reducible, rather than what you wrote"irreducible".

Comment: For prime it might be easier to prove the contrapositive: If $2\not|a$ and $2\not|b$ then $2\not| ab$. Assuming the first two, we can write $a=2a'+1$ and $b=2b'+1$. Then $ab=2(2a'b'+a'+b')+1$. For $2$ to divide this, it would need to divide $1$.

Comment: The terms "prime", "reducible", and "irreducible" are ordinarily intended to be used in the setting of *integral domains*, and the integers modulo 6 do not form an integral domain.  Focus on understanding how these concepts work and don't work in integral domains.

Comment: @user85667 `\nmid` looks better than `\not|` (and `\mid` looks better than `|`):$$a\mid b\quad a\nmid b$$versus$$a| b\quad a\not|b$$

Comment: Going from what you had written, you have $ab = 2(k-3t)$.  This allows us to transfer the question to $\mathbb{Z}$, answer it there, and then apply the quotient $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_6$ to find your $[s] \in \mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: Factorization theory is much more complicated in non-domains, i.e. when nontrivial zero-divisors exist, e.g. $\,x=(3+2x)(2−3x)\,$ in $\Bbb Z_6[x].\,$ Basic notions such as *associate* and *irreducible*  elements in a domain bifurcate into a few inequivalent notions in non-domains, e.g. see the papers cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732005/242).

Comment: Structurally: by the [third isomorphism theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857481/242) $\,\Bbb Z/6/(\Bbb 2/6)\cong \Bbb Z/2\,$ is a domain [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1229956/242) $\,2/6\,$ is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $[2] \ |\  [a][b]$, then there's  $[c]$ such that $2c=ab$ mod $6$, thus $2c+6k=ab$ for some integer $k$. Therefore either $a$ or $b$ is even. The images of even integers in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are $[0], [2], [4]$. All of those are divisible by $[2]$, hence either $[a]$ or $[b]$ will be divisible by $[2]$. Thus $[2]$ is prime.