# The relation between minimal ideals and zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

How we can prove this

> Theorem. Let $R$ be a reduced ring. Then $a\in ZD(R)$ (the zero divisors of $R$)  if and only if $a\in P$ for some minimal prime ideal $P$.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/518/78535) and others. See the answers there. There is a search capability that can be used to find questions and answers, see the box in the upper right corner of the page. Also you can use google with site:math.stackexchange.com, which is usually more accurate that the MSE search (but more cumbersome).

Answer (score 1):

I want to show if a∈Z(R)then a∈P.
Let x∈Z(R). Thus there exists y∈R such that y≠0 and xy=0.
Since R is reduced, y∉Nil(R), which is the intersection of all prime ideals of R. hence there exists at least a minimal prime ideal P of R which does not contain y.
Now, since xy=0∈P and P is prime, then x∈P.
How can I show the inverse? ( if a∈P then a∈Z(R) )