# The set consisting of all zero divisors in a commutative ring with unity contains at least one prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> I'm asked to prove that the set consisting of all zero divisors in a commutative ring with unity contains at least one prime ideal.

I can't even start in the proof, I've just defined my set but cant move on construction the ideal !

Comment: Nice Question.. Integral domain has $(??)$ as prime ideal... Can you see how and can you think of what would be the case of general commutative ring?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik for integral domains (p) is a prime ideal iff p is a prime number, then?

Comment: Check to see that your set is an ideal, then use the fact that $R/I$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is prime. By the way I think there are integral domains with prime ideals not generated by a single prime. It holds for principal ideal domains though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to approach this is to combine these two lemmas:

1. In a commutative ring, [there exist minimal prime ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_prime_(commutative_algebra)#Properties).
2. In a commutative ring with identity, [minimal primes consist entirely of zero divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors) (I use the convention that $0$ is a zero divisor here.)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking a follow-up question: is it true or false that an ideal which is maximal with respect to being contained in the set of zero divisors is necessarily prime? That's what I started trying to prove... I can post a new question if that's preferred, but I figured I might as well ask you first.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : I keep thinking about this extended question, but I don't have a conclusion either way. A counterexample would have to lie outside of reduced Noetherian rings. In those rings, the zero divisors are a union of prime ideals, and then prime avoidance tells you that an ideal maximal w.r.t. being all zero divisors is exactly one of these ideals.

Comment: [Posted a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627655/is-an-ideal-which-is-maximal-with-respect-to-the-property-that-it-consists-of-ze).

Comment: [Another more detailed approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44481/29335) that I ran across later.

Answer (score 8):

Let $Z$ be the set of all zero divisors in a commutative ring $R$. Note that $R \setminus Z$ is closed under multiplication.

Indeed, take $a, b \in R \setminus Z$ and assume $ab \in Z$. Then there exists nonzero $c \in R$ such that $$0 = (ab)c = a(bc)$$

If $bc \ne 0$ then $a(bc) = 0$ implies that $a$ is a zero divisor. On the other hand, if $bc = 0$ then $b$ is a zero divisor. A contradiction.

Now consider the family of all ideals in $R$ contained in $Z$:$$\mathcal{S} = \{I \trianglelefteq R : I \subseteq Z\}$$

Order $\mathcal{S}$ by inclusion. We have $\{0\} \in \mathcal{S}$, and for every chain $\mathcal{L}$ in $\mathcal{S}$ we have that $\bigcup \mathcal{L}$ is an upper bound for $\mathcal{L}$ which is contained in $\mathcal{S}$. Zorn's lemma implies that $\mathcal{S}$ has a maximal element $P$. We claim that $P$ is prime.

Let $A, B$ be two ideals in $R$ such that $AB \subseteq P$. Assume $A, B \not\subseteq P$. Then $P + A$ and $P + B$ are two ideals in $R$ which strictly contain $P$. Therefore, $P + A$ and $P + B$ intersect $R \setminus Z$. Let $p_1 + a \in (P + A) \cap R \setminus Z$ and $p_2 + b \in (P + B) \cap R \setminus Z$.

Since $R \setminus Z$ is closed under multiplication we have:

$$R \setminus Z \ni (p_1 + a)(p_2 + b) = p_1p_2 + p_1b + ap_2 + ab \in P$$

which is a contradiction since $P \subseteq Z$.

Therefore $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ contained in $Z$.

Comment: Does this proof work when the ring is non-commutative? And I think the existence of identity is necessary since this means R\Z is not empty and thus P is not equal to R.