# Correspondence between the ideals of a ring R and its localization at a submonoid S

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

I am studying the localization of a ring R at a submonoid S.
I am really confused of the form of the ideals in the localization.

In the case of the quotient ring A by an ideal I, it is defined a bijection between the ideals of A containg I and the ideals of A/I.

Is this rule true anymore in the localization of a ring at a submonid?

Can we say that there exists a bijection between the ideals of the ring R that does not meet S and the ideals of the localization of the ring R at the submonid S? Can we say that every ideal of the localization of the ring R at a submonoid S is of the form Is, where I is an ideal of R that does not meet S?

May you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2061480/133781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is such a bijection between the prime ideals of  $S^{-1}R$ and the  prime ideals of $R$ which do not meet $S$. For not necessarily prime ideals, every ideal in  $S^{-1}R$ has the form $S^{-1}\mathfrak a$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a\subset R$, but the correspondence is not necessarily injective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So, you mean that if J is an ideal in S^{-1}R, then J has the form S^{-1}\mathfrak I, for some ideal I of R, but not for all the ideals I of R. Is this correspondence always surjective? I think yes, since the correspondence between R and S^{-1}R such that a goes to a/s is surjective, but I do not know if I am right.

Comment: I mean that there may be several ideals in $R$ extending to the same ideal in $S^{-1}R$. So yes it is surjective. A reference (in the more genral context of submodules) is `Bourbaki`, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. II, *Rings and Modules of Fractions*, §2, n°4, prop. 10.

Comment: Ok, I will look for them when I'll pass to modules. Thank you!

Comment: F.y.i., if $\varphi:R\longrightarrow S^{-1}R$ is the canonical map, the ideal in $R$ which extends to $J$ in  $S^{-1}R$ is simply $\mathfrak I=\varphi^{-1}(J)$.