# In a reduced ring the set of zero divisors equals the union of minimal prime ideals.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> If $R$ is a reduced commutative ring with identity, why is the set $Z$ of zero divisors the union of minimal prime ideals?

I know that $Z$ is a union of associated primes, and that the intersection of all the prime ideals  is the zero ideal  in case $R$ is reduced, but can not reach any relationship between this information and the statement of my question.

Any help would be thanked!

Comment: See also [Why does a minimal prime ideal consist  of zero-divisors?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/27734/242)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20826/when-is-the-set-of-zero-divisors-equal-to-the-union-of-the-minimal-primes-in-a-r

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $Z(R)$ denote the set of zero divisors of $R$, and let $\{P_i\}$ denote the set of minimal primes. Suppose that $x\in R$ is a zero divisor. Choose some nonzero $y\in R$ such that $xy = 0$. Since $R$ is reduced, the intersection of all primes is just $\{ 0\}$. However, every prime contains a minimal prime so $\cap_i P_i = 0$ as well. Hence $y\not\in P_i$ for some minimal prime $P_i$. But $xy = 0\in P_i$ so $x\in P_i$. Thus, $Z(R)\subseteq \cup_i P_i$.

We have to prove now that minimal primes consist of zero divisors to show the reverse inclusion.

Let $P$ be a minimal prime of $R$. Let $S = \{ xy : x\not\in P, y\not\in Z(R) \}$. Then $S$ is multiplicatively closed and does not contain zero. Let $Q$ be a prime ideal maximal with respect to being disjoint from $S$; then $Q$ is prime. By definition of $S$, no element of $Q$ can be written as $1\cdot y$ where $y$ is not a zero divisor, so $Q$ consists of zero divisors.

By definition of $S$, no element of $Q$ can be written as $x\cdot 1$ with $x\not\in P$. Hence $Q\subseteq P$ and so $P = Q$ by minimality of $P$. QED

Comment: For the last part of the proof we can also refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors

Comment: @user26857 - Didn't notice that, thanks! However, I still feel it's more convenient to have a self-contained solution with notation in line with the entire answer rather than jump to another page with a different notation.

Answer (score 6):

Let $x\in R$ be a zero-divisor. We want to show that $x$ belongs to a minimal prime ideal. Let $y\in R$, $y\ne 0$ such that $xy=0$. If $x$ does not belong to any minimal prime, then from $xy=0\in\mathfrak p$, for $\mathfrak p$ a minimal prime, we get $y\in\mathfrak p$, so $y$ belongs to any minimal prime hence it is nilpotent and thus $y=0$, a contradiction.

The other containment follows from the [well known fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors) that every minimal prime consists of zero-divisors.

Answer (score 3):

This is because when $R$ is reduced, all associated prime ideals are minimal and hence $\operatorname{Ass} R= \operatorname{Min} R$.

*Some details:* The above assertion is true for *noetherian* rings. However, it remains true that the set of zero divisors in a reduced ring (not necessarily noetherian) ring is the union of all minimal prime ideals. To prove is, I'll use the *weakly associated* prime ideals, which is the relevant notion in the non-noetherian case (for noetherian rings,the two notions are the same).

Consider the natural mapping
$$R\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min} R}R/\mathfrak p.$$
Its kernel is the nilradical of $R$ so that, since $R$ is reduced, it is injective, hence
$$\operatorname{Ass} R\subset \operatorname{Ass}\Bigl(\bigoplus_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min} R}R/\mathfrak p\Bigr)=\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min} R}\operatorname{Ass}R/\mathfrak p =\operatorname{Min} R $$
so that $$Z(R)=\bigcup\limits_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Ass}R}\mathfrak p\subset \bigcup\limits_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min} R}\mathfrak p$$
Conversely, let $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min} R$ and $x\in\mathfrak p$. Consider the multiplicative set $$S=\bigl\{sx^k\mid s\in R\smallsetminus\mathfrak p,k\in\mathbf{N}\bigr\}.$$

**Claim:** $0\in S$. Note first $S$ contains $R\smallsetminus\mathfrak p$ and $x$. Now, if it were not true, there would be a prime ideal $\mathfrak p'$ disjoint from $S$, so $\mathfrak p'\subset \mathfrak p$, and the inclusion is strict since $x\notin \mathfrak p'$. But this contradicts the minimality of $\mathfrak p$.

Thus there exists an element $s\notin \mathfrak p$ and a natural number $k>0$ such that $sx^k=0$, but $sx^{k-1}\ne 0$. This proves every element of a minimal prime $\mathfrak p$ is a zero-divisor, and concludes the proof that
$$Z(R)=\bigcup\limits_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min} R}\mathfrak p.$$