# What is a minimal prime ideal of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

From Wikipedia:

> A prime ideal P is said to be a minimal prime ideal over an ideal I if it is minimal among all prime ideals containing I. (Note that we do not exclude I even if it is a prime ideal.) A prime ideal is said to be a minimal prime ideal if it is a minimal prime ideal over the zero ideal.

$\{0\}$ is always a prime ideal, so wouldn't this mean that in every ring only $\{0\}$ is minimal? Because for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ one always has $\{0\}\subset\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors) is a further answer to your title question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a commutative ring $R$ it is not necessarily true that the zero ideal $0 \subseteq R$ is a prime ideal.
This holds if and only if $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: You are right, thank you for reminding me.