# Questions in the proof that every minimal prime ideal in A is contained in Z(A)

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Edit : My question has been linked with this :[Why does a minimal prime ideal consist of zerodivisors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors) but this proof doesn't use localization, while I want to use localization. **So, kindly reopen my question.**

The following proof was outlined in my online class of commutative algebra and I was not able to understand and I asked to some of my friends and it's not clear with them also.

> Question: Let A be a ring. Then every minimal prime ideal in A is contained in Z(A)= the set of all zero divisors of A.

Proof: Let $P \in Spec A$ be a minimal prime ideal in A To show that $P\subseteq Z(A)$. Consider the local ring $A_P = S^{-1} A$, where S=A/P Then {$PA_P$}= $Spm A_P$ ( I understand this) = $Spec A_P$ and $Nil A_P=  P A_P$.

> Can you please tell how can I deduce that   $Spm A_P =Spec A_P$ and $Nil A_P=  P A_P$? I am not getting any ideas on how this should be proved.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of standard commutative algebra material: please kindly remember to search as much as possible before posting. Quite often you will find solutions for such questions pretty rapidly.

Comment: Just to make sure you understand the last line: there is a correspondence of prime ideals in $S^{-1}A$ and primes contained in $P$.   If you choose $P$ to be minimal, then there _are no other primes_, so that's why the spec equals maxspec.  The nilradical is the intersection of all primes, and if there is only one prime that is exactly the nilradical.

Comment: @rschwieb The linked answer doesn't uses localization.

Comment: @rschwieb It will really help me if you can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @rschwieb  I understand your 2nd comment completely .But how does $Spm A_P =  Spec A_P$ and $ Nil A_P = PA_P$?